# Return rows where one dataframe has value and other is missing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames with the same date index and columns. I would like to find the cases where a column has a value in one data frame but has a NaN in the other.

From the two data frames below then I would like to be able to retrieve an output for a given column that would look like this:

[image]

Or for the second column like:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dt_range = pd.date_range("2018-01-31", periods=12, freq="M")

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [np.nan,1,7,5,np.nan,6,3,np.nan,8,8,4,2],
                          'col2': [6,7,np.nan,5,np.nan,8,4,9,np.nan,8,np.nan,2],
                          'col3': [9,6,np.nan,7,5,8,np.nan,9,np.nan,8,6,6]},
                    index=dt_range)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [12,np.nan,70,58,np.nan,61,np.nan,70,85,85,np.nan,42],
                          'col2': [22,26,74,np.nan,60,21,np.nan,20,75,55,34,np.nan],
                          'col3': [93,np.nan,47,52,85,np.nan,29,np.nan,81,16,46,np.nan]},
                    index=dt_range)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we use the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) method on the `index` values like so :

```py
>>> df = pd.merge(df_1,
...               df_2,
...               how='left',
...               left_index=True,
...               right_index=True,
...               suffixes=['_df_1',
...                         '_df_2'])              
>>> df.head()
            col1_df_1   col2_df_1   col3_df_1   col1_df_2   col2_df_2   col3_df_2
2018-01-31  NaN         6.0         9.0         12.0        22.0        93.0
2018-02-28  1.0         7.0         6.0         NaN         26.0        NaN
2018-03-31  7.0         NaN         NaN         70.0        74.0        47.0
2018-04-30  5.0         5.0         7.0         58.0        NaN         52.0
2018-05-31  NaN         NaN         5.0         NaN         60.0        85.0
```

Then we write a function to select the two columns and the rows where one column has value and the other is missing to get the expected result :

```py
>>> def compare_columns_with_nan(col_name):
...     return df[((df[f'{col_name}_df_1'].isna()) | (df[f'{col_name}_df_2'].isna())) & ~((df[f'{col_name}_df_1'].isna()) & (df[f'{col_name}_df_2'].isna()))][[f'{col_name}_df_1', f'{col_name}_df_2']]
```

Here, the filter consists on two conditions :

- `(df[f'{col_name}_df_1'].isna()) | (df[f'{col_name}_df_2'].isna())` :
  the `col` in `df_1` is `NaN` or the `col` in `df_2` in `NaN`
- `~((df[f'{col_name}_df_1'].isna()) & (df[f'{col_name}_df_2'].isna())` :
  the two `cols` from `df_1` and `df_2` can't be both `NaN` (thanks to the `~` at the begining of the assertion)

Output for `col1` :

```py
>>> compare_columns_with_nan('col1')
            col1_df_1   col1_df_2
2018-01-31  NaN         12.0
2018-02-28  1.0         NaN
2018-07-31  3.0         NaN
2018-08-31  NaN         70.0
2018-11-30  4.0         NaN
```

Output for `col2` :

```py
>>> compare_columns_with_nan('col2')
            col2_df_1   col2_df_2
2018-03-31  NaN         74.0
2018-04-30  5.0         NaN
2018-05-31  NaN         60.0
2018-07-31  4.0         NaN
2018-09-30  NaN         75.0
2018-11-30  NaN         34.0
2018-12-31  2.0         NaN
```

Comment: I see that your function works but can you help me understand it better? I get that the first part is looking for conditions where either col_df1 or col_df2 is NA AND the second part of the condition is looking for conditions where both col_df1 AND col_df2 are not NA. Is this correct? How is it the case that this works? In the first condition if col_df1 is NA then how can it satisfy the second part?

Comment: Hi @stacksideways, I added an explanation in the answer. You do understand it correctly but with the `~` at the beginning of the second condition produce the "negative" of this second part. To answer the question from your comment : In the first condition if col_df1 is NA then how can it satisfy the second part? The second part ask for "not both col from df_1 and df_2 are NaN at the same time", so it accepts that if the col from df_1 is NaN and the one from df_2 is not NaN, it pass the filter.

Comment: Thanks tlentali, i see now where I was getting confused. The second condition is restricting for cases where both col_df1 & col_df2 are not NA. Thank you for the clarification.